# Configuring a server to run locally

Tags: mysql, node.js, backbone.js, configuration, server

I forked a [bookmarking project](https://github.com/dangrossman/Bookmarkly) and followed the installation and setup documentation until I got to

> Edit the configuration section of server.js to point to your database

That section looks like

```
/*  ==============================================================
    Configuration
=============================================================== */
//used for session and password hashes
var salt = '20sdkfjk23';

var client = new Client();
client.host = 'hostname';
client.user = 'username';
client.password = 'password';
client.database = 'bookmarks';

var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: salt, store: new RedisStore, cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 30 } }));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.logger({ format: ':method :url' }));

delete express.bodyParser.parse['multipart/form-data'];

app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'))
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
```

I've changed the instances of __dirname to the correct directory and I googled how to get what my computer's hostname is. I've swapped that in and tried using my username for my computer, but I'm embarrassed to admit that I'm not sure that's what I'm supposed to be doing here. Similarly, I've tried using password for my mysql database as the client.password value.

Regardless of what I enter in that section I get this message.

```
/Users/Spladow/repos/Bookmarkly/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:1246
        throw new Error('unknown type of connection in createClient()');
              ^
Error: unknown type of connection in createClient()
    at new exports.createClient (/Users/Spladow/repos/Bookmarkly/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:1246:15)
    at new RedisStore (/Users/Spladow/repos/Bookmarkly/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:51:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Spladow/repos/Bookmarkly/server.js:32:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

I'm really at a loss for what I should be changing and would appreciate suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the line of code that throws the error..? Is it supposed to be `new exports.createClient()` or `new express.createClient()`..?

Comment: BTW you don't have to change `__dirname`. It'll automatically point to your root folder. Try logging it's value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip on the __dirname.

I checked out /node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:1246:15) and the whole block is too long to include in the comments but it starts 

`exports.createClient = function(arg0, arg1, arg2){
    if( arguments.length === 0 ){

        // createClient()
        return createClient_tcp(default_port, default_host, {});

    and ends 

    } else {
        throw new Error('unknown type of connection in createClient()');
    }
}`

Comment: The line it's referencing in server.js is

`app.use(express.session({ secret: salt, store: new RedisStore, cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 30 } }));`

though. Is that more helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.I encounted exactly same problem~
Because I want a good demo of backbone for practicing then I found [Bookmarly](https://github.com/dangrossman/Bookmarkly).
Finally, I figured this out through google~

Here, is my solution:

1. start the [redis](http://redis.io/download) server. `redis-server`
2. change the `server.js` code.

change

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: salt, store: new RedisStore(), cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 30 } }));
```

to

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: salt, store: new RedisStore({host:'127.0.0.1', port:6379}), cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 30 } }));
```

Of course mysql must work.
Here some screen shot for you guys~

[image: mysql]
[image: redis-server]
[image: server.js]
[image: localhost]